# PSD matrix and non-negative polynomial

Tags: matrices, polynomials, semidefinite-programming

So I'm trying to prove that if there exists a $5 \times 5$ matrix $Q$ such that

$$Q \succeq0,\,\, a_{l-1} = \sum\limits_{i+j=l} Q_{ij} , l=1,\ldots,5$$

then there exists a fourth degree polynomial $p(x)$ such that 
$$ p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3 + a_4 x^4  \geq 0\,\,  \forall x\in \mathbb{R} $$

I just managed to finish proving the converse and I have some intuition that the PSD property of Q somehow implies non-negativity of $p(x)$ but I'm not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Did you mean $i+j=l$?

Comment: Edit 1: Yes, I did. Just edited it.

Comment: Are you using 0-based indicing for the rows and columns of $Q$? If 1-based indicing is used, you can't have $i+j=1$. So, how is $a_0$ defined?

Comment: I'm using $0$ based indexing.

Comment: Did I miss something? In your question, you say that "*there exists* a fourth degree polynomial $p(x)$", but $p$ is actually uniquely defined by $Q$ and so its existence is guaranteed. Also, apparently, the problem statement as it stands is false. For example, suppose $Q=I_5$. Then $p(x)=x+x^3$, which is not always nonnegative on $\mathbb R$.